# Windows Azure Cloud Service - entry point

Tags: web-services, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

I have created a "Windows Azure Cloud Service" project in VS2012.2 with a MVC4 web role.  When I run up the project it just gives me a web page.  I am trying to develop a web service back-end for my website so I want to be able to call web methods directly from my website which is also running in on Azure.

When F5 my project it just gives me a website. Should I be using a worker role instead of a web role?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your back-end web service along with your web role, then you can use it directly.

If you put your service in a worker role, then you need to open an input endpoint on your worker role so that it can be connected from out side of azure.

Or, you can create another website for your service and map to a virtual dictionary/application on your web role.

Comment: so how do I publish my web service to azure and connect it to my website? I was expecting to see a web method definition in the project somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You may use both, but a web role is easiest as it sets up everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use web role in your scenario, the reason being publishing a web role is pretty straight forward.